# Python3.5.0 and Pycharm interpreter error

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter, tarfile

#### Python3.5.0 downloaded to specific place

I install to my home/test/python3.5.0

#### Pycharm downloaded

I install Pycharm via sudo apt-get-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm

#### Pycharm interpreter

I want to use specific interpreter inside test/python3.5.0's pyhton.exe but give me error like this.

Firstly,

Python packaging tools not found. Install packaging tools.

Then  I press it,

Failed to install Python packaging tool

Execute command

```
/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/packaging_tool.py untar 
/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/setuptools-18.1.tar.gz
```

Error occured

```
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

How can I solve this problem ?